# Python - Replace email from list by numbers

Tags: python, list, io

I want to replace all email addresses in a text file with random numbers. Now I have found those emails, but they are all returned in a list by regex re.findall()

For instance, the output is like:

```
['xyz123@gmail.com']
```

So when I try to replace this output by random numbers, I would get error saying

```
Can't convert 'list' object to str implicitly
```

My code is here:

```
with open('a.txt', 'r') as file1:
    with open('b.txt', 'w') as file2:
        for line in file1:
            email = re.findall(......,line)
            file2.write(line.replace(email, random.random()))
```

And the rest code is omitted since they have no use here. So could anyone tell me how to deal with this list? I have tried to explicitly coerce list to string with str(), but it failed.

Answer (score 0):

Avoid the issue of converting the list object by having the re module do all the work for you.  re.sub or regex pattern object.sub will replace substrings that match your pattern with the output of a function that takes a regex match object as input.

```
#pass each line through this:
def mask_matches( string, regex ):
    ''' substrings of string that match regular expressions pattern object regex
    are replaced with random.random( ).
    '''
    def repl( mobj ):
        replacement = random.random( )
        return( replacement )
    return( regex.sub( repl, string ) )

#so if `email` is your regex pattern object, thenyour last line looks something like this:
file2.write( mask_matches( line, email ) )
```

Comment: thanks for this. But I would receive a "AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'sub'" in the line "return(regex.sub(repl, string))

Comment: As I tried to explain in the code comment, `email` in the code I suggested isn't meant to refer to your `email` list( ).  Sorry, I didn't go quite far enough for you to be able to *just* copy and paste.  `email` should be a regex pattern object.  There is no need for you to be generating the list in the first place.  Instead of your line beginning `email = re.findall` you should have one that begins `email = re.compile`.  You don't show your regex pattern so I can't write copy-and-paste code to replace that line.

Answer (score 0):

Try loop over email and replace, as like:-

```
with open('a.txt', 'r') as file1:
    with open('b.txt', 'w') as file2:
        for line in file1:
            email = re.findall(......,line)
            for em in email:
                file2.write(line.replace(em, random.random()))
```

Comment: Thanks for this. But I have already tried this, and it returns "Can't convert 'float' object to str implicitly"

Comment: I didn't executed this, yes may be problem is here. We need to change last line . Use it like this and get a successful successful execution line.replace(em, random.random()) In next line file2.write(STR(line))